# Aproximating a function on SO(3)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

By $SO(3)$ I mean rotation matrices. Let $\cal{L}=\{f:[0,l]\to \rm{SO}(3)\} \cap L^1([0,l];\mathbb{R}^{3\times3})$. How to approximate funkctions from $\cal{L}$ with functions from $\cal{W}=\{f:[0,l]\to \rm{SO}(3)\}\cap W^{1,2}([0,l];\mathbb{R}^{3\times3})$?

So having $f\in\cal{L}$ I need a sequence $(g_n)_n \subset \cal{W}$ so that

$$ \| f - g_n \|_{L^1} \to 0.$$

My try #2:
From $f$ go to $h$ such that $h(t)=\log(f(t))\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}_\rm{skew}$ where $\log$ is matrix logarithm. If I would know that $h\in L^1([0,l];\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}_\rm{skew})$ then I could use approximation in that normed space by molifiers to construct $h_n\in W^{1,2}([0,l];\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}_\rm{skew})$ such that $h_n \to h$ in $L^1$, and then maybe for $g_n=\exp(h_n)$ we would have $g_n \to f$ in $L^1$.

My try #1 was directly molifying $f$, but the resulting molifications are not functions on $SO(3)$ anymore.

Comment: View $f$ as a function into $S^3$ using the double cover of $SO(3)$, approximate it with good old polynomials in $\mathbb R^4$, project each point radially to $S^3$ (which is nice and smooth), and map back to $SO(3)$?

Comment: The double cover most conveniently constructed using quaternions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm What I thought in #1 was similar to this. The problem I ran into is that projecting radialy is fine until the curve that is being projected runs through the origin. When that happens the continuity of projection is lost. We could change the center of radial projection to a different point inside the ball. Then, we could still have a problem in case the curves that make up the family of molifiers (or polynomials) form a dense subset in the ball. I tried complicating the choice of the origin of projection by moving it around for $t\in[0,l]$, but I didn't feel in control...

Comment: @MateKosor: Since polynomials can approximate the target curve _uniformly_, just let the first approximation be "at most $1/4$ away from the target curve in any coordinate" and decrease that tolerance after that. Then the approximation can't possibly reach the origin, since that's to far away from the $S^3$ shell that the target curve lies in.

Comment: The target curve is in $L^1$ space (see the question), which means it is generally not continuous, and so can not be approximated uniformly by a continuous function. It can be approximated poinwise, almost anywhere.